# very strange freestyle behaviour

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

so i know there are problems with the freestyle module, and it sometimes does not occlude edges properly leading to incorrect lines being drawn. however, i've attached a blend file in which freestyle draws lines where there are no edges what-so-ever. the lines it draws are not bad occlusion, they're not triangulation edges. they appear seemingly for no reason. here's what i mean:
[image: weird freestyle behaviour]

if anyone has any ideas for remedying this, i'd greatly appreciate them.

link to blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mzJaanxAgmIhWYhACdO9qsR0aiVYnvGP/view?usp=sharing

blender version: 3.1.2

Comment: I'm afraid this might not help much, but I can't reproduce this.. I've tried quite hard. It will be interesting to see what others have to say.

Comment: The problem occurs for me as well - if you join all the "cubes" into one object, the problem seems to go away on the top, but you start losing freestyle lines on the sides. Makes me think it has something to do with the arrangement/proximity of the "cubes" and/or the freestyle settings and how they may be interpreting the "break points" between objects.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected - the problem seems to stem from Z-Fighting among the "cubes" - most of them aren't affected - I guess one catches it at bad angle. Regardless, if mathematical purity isn't paramount to your project, you can solve the issue by scaling the highlighted object by something as little as .999 on the X and Y axes (<kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> > .999).

[image: Scale]

Comment: hi, thanks for the solution. it does make sense that this is something to do with the proximity of the objects. what's interesting is that this is an orthographic projection, so there's nothing that would be parallel to the unwanted lines. assuming this is related to the objects z-fighting, i still wonder how this leads to the freestyle behaviour. after all, where are the lines being drawn? an outline? silhouette? contour? curious, thanks for the answer

Comment: Yeah. I'm not sure - I tried deleting all the side faces of the block and the one next to it, but it still gave the same artifact - only scaling seemed to work for me